# What are the vshost files in my c# bin folder?

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the purpose of vshost.exe file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774187/what-is-the-purpose-of-vshost-exe-file)

What do the vshost files do?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774187/what-is-the-purpose-of-vshost-exe-file

Answer (score 1):

> vhost is a hosting process used by
>   Visual Studio (read: you should not
>   run it directly) that improves
>   debugging performance, enables partial
>   trust debugging, and enables design
>   time expression evaluation.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/irenak/archive/2005/12/19/505429.aspx

Comment: It helps if you quote some of the link - that way people can see it's relevance before clicking through. It also helps guard against link rot (unlikely with MSDN links, but you never know).