# Four binaries out of Visual Studio/C# compilation

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I compiled a simple program (HIR) in Visual Studio 10.0 (C#), and I got the four binaries in a Debug/Release directory.

- HIR.exe
- HIR.pdb
- HIR.vshost.exe
- HIR.vshost.exe.manifest

I guess that HIR.exe is the binary, and HIR.pdb is debugging info. However, what are HIR.vshost.exe and HIR.vshost.exe.mainfest for?

In terms of deployment, do I have to let the users install all the four files?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774187/what-is-the-purpose-of-vshost-exe-file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to deploy the 'vshost' files, these are just to help with the performance of debugging in Visual Studio.

Just to confirm, from MSDN

> Hosting process files (.vshost.exe)
>   are for use by Visual Studio and
>   should not be run directly or deployed
>   with your application

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185331%28v=VS.100%29.aspx