# what's the purpose for vshost file?

Tags: c#, .net

Under Visual studio, I found the console program is actually ***vshost.exe, I would like to know the purpose of this file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of vshost.exe file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774187/what-is-the-purpose-of-vshost-exe-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The hosting process is a feature in
>   Visual Studio 2005 that improves
>   debugging performance, enables partial
>   trust debugging, and enables design
>   time expression evaluation. The
>   hosting process files contain vshost
>   in the file name and are placed in the
>   output folder of your project.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185331(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Those are used when the application is started from within Visual Studio. It's for the interaction with the IDE, it's not needed when you run the application on it's own.