# What's the best way to get the full path and filename of the invoked executable in c#?

Tags: c#

Given the following code:

```
using System;

namespace Sandbox
{
   class CommandLine
   {
      static void Main()
      {
         String[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
         String executable = args[0];
         String[] paramList = getParamList(args);

         System.Console.WriteLine("Directory ....... {0}", Environment.CurrentDirectory);
         System.Console.WriteLine("Executable ...... {0}", args[0]);
         System.Console.WriteLine("Params .......... {0}", String.Join(", ", paramList));
      }

      private static String[] getParamList(String[] args)
      {
         String[] paramList = new String[args.Length - 1];

         for (int i = 1; i < args.Length; i++) 
         {
            int j = i - 1;
            paramList[j] = args[i];
         }

         return paramList;
      }
   }
}
```

... Saved as commandline.cs and `csc`’d to commandline.exe

I’d like to get the full path and filename of the execuatable being invoked. This code almost does it, however it’s not 100% accurate:

- if I call it as `commandline.exe foo bar baz` from the same directory; all is well
- if I call it as `commandline foo bar baz` from the same directory, I only get the filename sans extension; not what I want
- if I call it as `sandbox\commandline foo bar baz` from the parent directory; I get the relative path and partial filename

I'm sure there's a much easier way of getting the full path and filename of the executable *other* than string manipulation, right?

Comment: .Net is a vast framework indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will be

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName
```

Be aware, though, that when running your application from within Visual Studio, this will most likely return full path to a [vshost file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774187/what-is-the-purpose-of-vshost-exe-file).

Answer (score 2):

[Application.ExecutablePath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.executablepath.aspx).

Note that this requires a reference to `system.windows.forms`.

Answer (score 1):

use `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase`

Answer (score 0):

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(‌​).Location)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string path = System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase;
```

[Application.ExecutablePath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.executablepath.aspx) will give you path of the application that executed your code.  For instance app that called your dll.  The line above provides you full path to your app.

You can read more at: [HOW TO: Determine the Executing Application's Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa457089.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This is what we use.  Seems to work from Console, WinForms, and WPF apps running from Visual Studio or standalone.

```
System.Reflection.Assembly entryAssembly = 
    System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
string applicationPath = entryAssembly != null ? entryAssembly.Location :
    System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
string applicationDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(applicationPath);
```