# Excessive files on build

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, build

I have a C#/Winforms project in Visual Studio. I can build it, and all is fine, but it generates a lot of excessive files. Is there any way to avoid this? It is not very intentional, if you want to distribute it to non-technical stakeholders during the process.

I have three files (bold formated) which seems to be required. After some research, I fould a way to [avoid the .vshost files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513387/disabling-the-vshost-exe-and-miscellaneous-files-from-being-created-on-build) (formated as *italic*), but I still have some files left, which I cannot figure out what does (normal formating).

- **SomeLibrary.Json.dll**
- SomeLibrary.Json.xml
- **SomeAPI.Api.Client.dll**
- SomeAPI.Api.Client.xml
- **MyProgram.exe**
- MyProgram.exe.config
- MyProgram.pdb
- *MyProgram.vshost.exe*
- *MyProgram.vshost.exe.config*
- *MyProgram.vshost.exe.manifest*

How do I make a **release build** without these remaining non-required files?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I tried searching but found nothing. Possibly due to the very cryptic name. I will check if this solves my problem, and then address the possible duplicate post issue.

Comment: @Abhishek thanks once again. I manage to remove three unnessesary files from the build, but I still have a few files left, which does not seem to have any effect? I edited the post accordingly.

Comment: @Noceo these aren't non-required files and they *are* well documented. Those are the files used when you debug your application. If you don't want them, make a Release build

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am making a release build, but I can see that I missed that in my original post. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The `xml` files contain documentation used to make intellisense work when referencing the dll's with the same name. If these are your libraries, you can go to *Project Properties* and uncheck `XML documentation file`. Otherwise, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2300049/292411
- `pdb` files contain debugging information. You can go to *Project Properties -> Build -> Advanced* and set `Debug Info` to `none` if you don't want to generate this file
- The `.config` files are configuration files generated by Visual Studio probably because your project contains an `App.Config` file. If you're running the application without the `.config` files, you might as well delete the `App.Config` file

Abhishek's comment already contained information that helped you remove the vshost files.

Personally I find it easier to just pick the files myself, especially when you're working in a team you sometimes just want to settle with what everyone's used to.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think that brings me to a point, where I now understand **all** the files (more or less at least). I will mark this as the correct answer, but make sure to check Abhishek's comment as well.