# change the default printer icon in windows xp

Tags: printing, icons

I am developing a virtual printer driver and after installing it, The system show the default icon, So how should I change it to some custom icon in windows XP.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10223655/1932105

Comment: @AhmedEkri it appears that Jimit wants to change the icon for the virtual printer, not for an EXE or window.

Comment: How to specifically change the icon for the printer in windows XP ?