# How to change icon of program in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

Just wondering, how do i change the built program icon to something i want? I can't seem to figure this out, and i don't really like the default icon

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change default icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223477/change-default-icon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow these steps :

1 - In Solution Explorer, choose a project node (not the Solution node).

2 - On the menu bar, choose Project, Properties.

3 - When the Project Designer appears, choose the Application tab.

(Visual Basic) In the Icon list, choose an icon (.ico) file.

4 - C# Near the Icon list, choose the  button, and then browse to the location of the icon file that you want.