# Change default icon and name of shortcut In installer project

Tags: c#, icons, installation, rename, shortcut

I already saw answers for this question and they were voted up and marked as answers, but they didn't work for me

I am trying to create shortcut of my application when the installer installs it

I already saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223477/change-default-icon) but didn't work for me

I have added my icon to the file system in for the installer project

[image: add icon to file system]

And renamed the shortcut and selected the icon
I tried selecting it from the primary output and from the added ico file

[image]

And the result is no name and no shortcut

[image]

The original executable also have no icon

[image]

I don't know what I am making wrong
Please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out what was the problem

When rebuilding the solution, the installer project was not rebuilt, so I did a right click on the installer project and rebuilt it

And it was just that :)