# Icon of Window form application

Tags: vb.net, icons

[image: My window form application]

How can I change this icon with another icon, I use visual studio 2017 to make this window form application. I can only change the icon of this application on the taskbar.

I hope everyone can help me change this icon

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change default icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223477/change-default-icon)

Answer (score 0):

### If you're looking at changing the icon on the actual forms in the application:

- Open your specific form in the designer view
- Right-click on the form and select 'Properties'
- Inside of the 'Properties' window, you can find 'Icon' and change it there.

Note: Make sure it's a .ico file type.

---

If have any other questions or need to change the application icon, let me know and I can help out.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It only changes the icon on the taskbar but in the settings app & features section it doesn't change.