# vhost.exe. Why is that needed?

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the purpose of vshost.exe file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774187/what-is-the-purpose-of-vshost-exe-file)

When a .NET application is built, a second exe with name **applicationname.vhost.exe** is created along with the actual application. Or its there along with the actual application when I opened the bin folder.

The **applicationname.vhost.exe** seems to do nothing when I tried to open it.

What is its purpose?

Comment: you would need less time googling it than formulating your question here..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> The hosting process is a feature in Visual Studio that improves
>   debugging  performance, enables partial trust debugging, and enables
>   design time expression  evaluation. The hosting process files contain
>   vshost in the file name and are  placed in the output folder of your
>   project.

[Hosting Process (vshost.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185331(v=vs.80).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

This is the "hosting process". It is created whenever you build a project in the Visual Studio IDE. Its purpose is to provide support for improved F5 performance, partial trust debugging, and design time expression evaluation.
VSHOST should never be run directly, and shouldn't be deployed with your application.

[Answered also here!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774187/what-is-the-purpose-of-vshost-exe-file)