# What is needed to run a WPF app?

Tags: wpf, deployment, visual-studio-2013, exe, vshost.exe

I copied my .exe, plus its vshost.exe, plus the sqlite database file it uses, but it won't run outside of Visual Studio. There's no err msg when I 2-click my .exe - it just won't run. What is it lacking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're on your local box, you would need:

- The main `application.exe` ([NOT vshost.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774187/what-is-the-purpose-of-vshost-exe-file) - These are for Visual Studio debugging only.)
- `application.exe.config` if there are any settings associated with the app.
- Any DLLs the application references. Since you're using SQLite, you likely have a dependency on some SQLite library.

If you're deploying to another computer, then you should also consider the following:

- Is the .NET Framework you're targeting installed on the target computer?
- You should also build in "Release" instead of "Debug", since debug DLLs may be missing.

Generally, the following files are *NOT* necessary:

- `.pdb` files
- Any `vshost` files

Comment: Yep; what was needed was:
To deploy the .exe, need:
Multilingual.exe
Multilingual.exe.config
Multilingual.sqlite
sqlite3.dll

Comment: I just wrote a tip on Code Project related to this: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/851645/Quick-and-Dirty-Deployment-of-apps